# How to show that complete and pseudocompact implies sequentially compact (in a metric space)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I have proved that pseudocompact implies completeness in a metric space, which is, as I understand it, a step to proving pseudocompactness implies compactness. How do I show complete and pseudocompact implies (sequentially) compact?

Comment: Prove pseudocompact implies total boundedness.   See also [A metric space is compact iff it is pseudocompact](/q/1457629/).